# I need a loop which can add a value to my initial value for only some iterations

Tags: r

I need a loop of 32 years that will check if the current year is (lets say a multiple of 4) and if so add a value to my value of interest

I've tried using ifelse, but I don't think I really understand how the function works.

```
result <- rbind(c(t,Na))
Na <- 10
for (t in 1:32){
  ifelse(t=c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32),(Na <- Na+((t/4)*20)),(Na <- Na))
  result <- rbind(result,round(c(t,Na),2))
}
```

Comment: I believe your thinking of this the wrong way.  I'd look into the modulus operator `%%` if I were you to determine what numbers are factor-able

Comment: Ifelse example: result <- ifelse(some_condition,  value+1, value-1). Lets say value <- 1. If some_condition == TRUE, results will be 2. If some_condition == FALSE, results will be 0

Comment: Take a look at how logical operators (`%in%`, `==`, `>`, etc) are used in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would be willing not to use a for loop, you could go like this (untested):

```
t <- 1:32
idx <- which(t %% 4==0)
Na <- rep(10,32)
Na[idx] <- Na[idx]+20*t[idx]/4
result <- cbind(t, cumsum(Na))
```

The second line filters the indices of those components that needs special treatment. The third line creates a vector of length 32 with all components being 10. The fourth line applies the special treatment. The last line uses `cumsum` to calculate the cumulative sum.